# How to stream mp3 from server-side keeping the file hidden?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, stream

I'm trying to play mp3 files from server-side to client-side. Where the client access the server passing some ID and the server return the file.

Right now, how this is working?

Well, using Laravel (server-side) and AngularJS (client-side) on distinct urls, i'm able to play the song.

But, if I get the request response I'm able to download the song.

So, what would be the good way to work so that information wouldn't be visible to the user?

Answer (score 1):

I would write some sort of file proxy.

You have to move your files out of the publicly accessible area. F.a one level above the page root. So it is not possible to get the data directly.
Then you need a server side script, that gets the data and returns it with the headers you need.

Here is an example (plain PHP):

```
/**
 * @param string $file_name
 * @param string $mime
 * @param bool $download
 */
public function fileProxyAction($file_name, $mime, $download = false) {

    if(basename($file_name) != $file_name) return 'Filename not valid!';

    $path = '... your path goes here';
    $file = $path.$file_name;
    if (!(file_exists($file) && is_readable($file))) return 'The file "'.$file_name.'" could not be found!';


    ob_clean();

    if($download === false) {

        header('Content-type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));

        $open = @ fopen($file, 'rb');
        if ($open) {
            fpassthru($open);
            exit;
        }

    } else {

        // download
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($file));
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        header("Cache-control: private"); // open files directly
        readfile($file);
        die;
    }

}
```

Laravel has an excellent [Built-In-Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem). Check it out. I'm sure you can optimize my method with it.

**EDIT**

If you need to check a token or something, you shouldn't call the `fileProxyAction` directly by the router. Instead let your router call a Method which checks the token or what ever you're using ;)

Example (pseudo code):

```
Route::get('/mp3/{id}/{token}', function($id, $token) {
    if($token !== Session::get('token')) return App::abort(401);
    $name = Mp3::findOrFail($id)->name;
    $mime = Mp3::findOrFail($id)->mime;

    return $this->fileProxyAction($name, $mime);
});
```

Comment: Right! The back-end is change the header and opening the file. Anyway copying that link and accessing from browser I'm able to download de file, because my back-end is returning the "file content".

Comment: Before you call the `fileProxyAction` you can do what ever you need to verify the user. See edit.